# Selenium how to get text element

Tags: python, selenium

How to I select in python selenium this element "51,756 results"?

```
<h1 id="results-list__title" class="t-white t-16 truncate" title="Worldwide">
            Worldwide</h1>
<small aria-live="polite" class="t-white display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal">
              51,756 results

<!---->          </small>
```

my try:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('t-white display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal')
    
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//h1[contains(@class, "t-white display-flex t-12 t-black--light t-normal")]').text
```

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('small').text
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag' or class_tag

Comment: I've updated. Please try again and let me know